# How can I use the :first-child selector w/ shadow DOM's <content> element?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'd like to extract the first paragraph from a custom element's content (as a summary). I would expect the following to work:

```
<polymer-element name="x-thing" noscript>
  <template>
    <segment class="summary">
      <content select="p:first-child"></content>
    </segment>
    <segment>
      <content></content>
    </segment>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Unfortunately, the `<content select="p:first-child">` doesn't appear to match anything :(

[Here's a corresponding codepen](http://codepen.io/nevir/pen/CmzEB/?editors=100).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `:not()` is supported in the Shadow DOM spec: http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#dfn-matching-criteria

Relevant bug: http://crbug.com/343332

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like pseudos within `:not` do work (M37). I can [fake it via `select=":not(:nth-child(n+2))"`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iCyvt?editors=100). Intended, or bug?

Comment: Aside: I'd _really like_ to have this behavior in some form or another. I suspect it's a relatively common case (extracting excerpts/headers/summaries from content).